# How to remove all the detected lines from the original image using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, straight-line-detection

I am trying to remove all the lines present in the image.
I am able to detect the lines but when I am trying to remove the lines, I am still getting few small lines in the final image. I have used `cv2.getStructuringElement` to get both the horizontal and vertical lines. In some cases, the final image is getting completely distorted and I am not able to move forward

The image is taken from google

[image: Original Image]
[image: Lines detected]

```
    res = verticle_lines_img + horizontal_lines_img 
    res = cv2.bitwise_not(res)
    fin=cv2.bitwise_or(img_bin, res,mask =cv2.bitwise_not(res))
    fin= cv2.bitwise_not(fin)
    exp =255-res
    final = cv2.bitwise_and(exp,img_bin)
    final = cv2.bitwise_not(final)
    exp = ~exp
    finalised = cv2.bitwise_and(img_bin,final)
    finalised = cv2.bitwise_not(finalised)
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold to obtain binary image
- Remove horizontal lines
- Remove vertical lines

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to get a binary image

```
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

From here we construct a special horizontal kernel to detect horizontal lines. Once the lines are detected, we fill in the lines to effectively remove the line

```
# Remove horizontal
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)
```

Similarly, to remove vertical lines, we construct a special vertical kernel

```
# Remove vertical
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,10))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)
```

Here's the detected lines in green

[image]

Result

[image]

You can fine tune the results by adjusting the kernel size. For instance, changing `(10,1)` to say `(15,1)` will tighten the line detection while lowering it to `(5,1)` will loosen the detection

Full Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

# Remove vertical
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,10))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks @nathancy, the output image that I am getting now is better than what I was getting earlier. Although there are still long horizontal lines that are present in the image. Any advice on how to get them removed?

Comment: Try like `(20,1)` or `(50,1)`, its experimental. There is a tradeoff, you don't want a too small kernel which takes away the text but you also dont want a too big kernel where it doesnt detect anything. You can try also modifying the "line width" by increasing the other parameter such as `(20, 2)`

Comment: For me changing the width of the contours to 3 did the job. Thank you @nathancy